# How to navigate to a sub directory through a proxy with FTPWebRequest

Tags: proxy, ftp, ftpwebrequest

I am currently trying to log on to a ftp server via an ftp proxy. Using the following snippet

```
 async {
          let r = FtpWebRequest.Create("ftp://<ftp-proxy-address>") :?> FtpWebRequest
          r.Method <- WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails      
          r.Timeout <- req.Timeout.TotalMilliseconds |> int
          r.Proxy <- null 
          r.Credentials <- NetworkCredential("user@host/subdirectory","password")
          use! response = r.AsyncGetResponse()
          use sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), req.Encoding)
          let result = handler sr
          return result
        }
```

However this always logs me on to the user directory root not into the subdirectory I have specified in the user credentials. Is there a way to get this to work?

**Note** It seems to work if I do not use a FTP proxy instead specify a HTTP proxy.. I can see the CWD command being issued and I end up in the directory I expected

Answer (score 0):

You have to logon first and then change directory.

Comment: Sadly, this does not work there is no way to issue the CWD/CD command via FtpWebRequest. This is done transparently for you, but doesn't seem to work with a proxy